# Height Calculation with Spherical Harmonics and Legendre Function: with R Code

Tags: r, height

Is there any built-in function in R for computing the legendre function rather than `pracma::legendre`? The `pracma::legendre` function is indeed commonly used for computing Legendre polynomials, but it may encounter numerical issues for high degree and order. Using this function for high degree and order, we get `NaN, -Inf, +Inf`, or a big number of power `e+280`.
I have the degree `l` and order `m` as follows:

```
l = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
m = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3)
theta = pi/180 * c(rep(58.5, 5), rep(58.25, 5))
lambda = pi/180 * rep(c(33, 33.25, 33.5, 33.75, 34), 2)
bar_c <- c(1.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00, -4.84e-04, -3.38e-10,  2.44e-06,  9.57e-07,  2.03e-06,  9.05e-07,  7.21e-07)
bar_s <-c(0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  1.45e-09, -1.40e-06,  0.00e+00,  2.48e-07, -6.19e-07,  1.41e-06)
N_max = 10 
R =6371000
```

I want to compute the following:
[image]

Comment: Check the **orthopolynom** package. It provides unnormalized and normalized Legendre polynomials, but not sure this is the same normalization.